# How do you handle React component hierarchies to ensure state cleanup?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am creating my first React application and I am struggling with a bug that I don't quite understand. I mount a component (A), which then mounts another component (B), which then mounts another (C). User interaction causes the parent component (A) to be unmounted without any trouble (using React.unmountComponentAtNode()). I then remount the component to start the activity over again and I begin getting the error on calls to setState():

Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: replaceState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.

I also get errors related to state variables keeping their values from the previous exercise.

So my questions are, how do I ensure that there is no state leftover from prior exercises? According to React documentation, React.unmountComponentAtNode(), will clean up the state of the components, yet I am clearly seeing the children of unmounted components carrying state after being mounted a second time.

Additional info: I am using React with Nodejs

Comment: Can you isolate the problem and share a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

After unmounting the component it remains in the virtual dom and is still able to receive socket.io commands. I was able to prevent the errors using isMounted().